# How to simulate a "no route to host" error?

Tags: sockets, networking, cfnetwork

I'm debugging a certain issue that only appears when I get a "no route to host error" from the socket (on client's networks). However, this error does not happen on my own network, so I can't reproduce the problem, making it difficult to test the fix.

If it matters, I'm using CFNetwork (on iOS), but I think it's just a wrapper around plain C sockets.

Comment: I've gotten this message when using messed up local addresses - like [::]:12322 with the sendTo function.

Answer (score 1):

Alter the address you are trying to reach so that the host truly is unreachable.   Either pick one that doesn't exist or just mangle the address (leave it blank).   You may also be able to put firewalls in the way or set your router to block traffic.